# seeking a faster way to drop all placeholders from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I receive a lot of .CSV and excel files full of data from other people and they always fill blank fields with random placeholders such as , N/a, etc. I have written a function to iterate over a column and remove a list of these placeholders from that dataset. If the issue affects the entire dataset I can even iterate over all column and clean the placeholders from the entire dataset. The issue is that it is very slow to iterate over every column and row and possible placeholder. I am hoping someone can show me a faster or even just a mor pythonic way of accomplishing this task. Thanks!

## My current function:

```
def drop_placeholders(dataframe, column, placeholder_list=['N/A', 'N/a', 'n/a', 'NaN', 'none', '<none>', 'Unassigned', 'Not Reported', '- None -']):
    '''Iterate over a column in a dataframe and blank out any fields containing a value in the sloplist IE: N/a, n/a, <none>, etc.'''
    column_data = []
    column_iloc = dataframe.columns.get_loc(column)
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        row_data = row[column_iloc]
        if row_data in placeholder_list:
            column_data.append('')
        else:
            column_data.append(row_data)
    dataframe = dataframe.drop(column, axis=1)
    dataframe[column] = column_data
    return(dataframe)
```

## Drop all placeholders from a single colunm

```
df = drop_placeholders(df, colunm)
```

## drop all placeholders from entire dataframe

```
for colunm in list(df):
    df = drop_placeholders(df, colunm)
```

I saw that pandas as a dropna() function built in but could not figure out how to specify a list of placeholders.

any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `read_csv` and `read_excel` accept a `na_values` argument, which is described in the docs as follows:

> **na_values** : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific
>   per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted
>   as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’,
>   ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’,
>   ‘null’.

This means you can pass your extra values through when you read the file and it should be considerably faster.

Basically, where you read the file do

```
placeholders = ['N/A', 'N/a', 'n/a', 'NaN', 'none', '<none>', 'Unassigned', 'Not Reported', '- None -']
df = read_csv(filename, na_values=placeholders)
```

Now that will read the file with NaN in the placeholder positions. To drop the rows containing these values, use [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=[column])  # For a single column
df = df.dropna()  # for all rows containing nans
df = df.dropna(how='all')  # to drop only rows where all columns are nan
```

Comment: This is great, one potential issue is that OP may need different placeholders for different columns (hence `placeholder_list` is an argument). I don't think `read_csv` caters for this.

Comment: Yes, I do have different placeholder values for different columns, which likely won't be an issue most of the time so doing this na_values will likely work 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating dataframe rows will be inefficient. Doing so repeatedly must be painfully so.

You can use Boolean indexing via [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
def drop_placeholders(df, col, L=['N/A', 'N/a', 'n/a', 'NaN', 'none', '<none>',
                                  'Unassigned', 'Not Reported', '- None -']):
    df.loc[df[col].isin(L), column] = ''
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if the `CSV` file is not huge, you can also read the `CSV` into a `DataFrame` and use masking as mentioned by @jpp and drop all the rows containing it by chaining [`pd.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). May not the most efficient way, but it's a way to deal with `DataFrame` object without traversing through each column.

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
     A    B         C
0    0   10       100
1    1  n/a       101
2    2   12       102
3  N/A   13       103
4    4   14  - None -
5    5   15       105
6    6   16       106
7    7   17       107
8    8   18       108
9    9   19       109


In [53]: df[-df.isin(placeholder_list)].dropna()
Out[53]: 
   A   B    C
0  0  10  100
2  2  12  102
5  5  15  105
6  6  16  106
7  7  17  107
8  8  18  108
9  9  19  109
```

**Please note** the `-` sign in the second code